# Как соотносятся понятия "рубрикация" и "композиция"?

Tags: оформление-текста

... и если рубрикация - это членение текста на составные части: абзацы, параграфы, подзаголовки, заголовки, - то для чего нужно понятие "рубрикация"? Ведь понятие "композиция" само по себе и подразумевает членение текста?
Помогите развести эти понятия. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://geum.ru/next/art-190505.leaf-7.php Композиция и рубрикация курсовой работы. Методические указания рецензента. Ознакомьтесь с публикацией.